# Jmeter: How to generate Random numbers in increment Format in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an HTTP request which each time accepts **only** a different Value in it.

So I have used Random Variable function for the same and it's working fine for me,

Now I want to generate the same numbers in an incremental format with Prefix.

Here is the random variable expression I have used :

```
"${__V(ABCD${__Random(1,1000000)})}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Random function doesn't guarantee incremented numbers, surprisingly they will be *random**.

If you need to get unique incremented numbers consider switching either to [Counter Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) or to [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter)

[image: JMeter Counter]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [Counter] component and Random function

Add Counter

- Start with: 10000
- Number Format: 00000
- Reference Name: cnt

Use in your call your number will be incremented with 3 last digits randomized:

```
${__V(ABCD${cnt}${__Random(1,1000)})}
```

Output will be as:

- **ABCD10000**487
- **ABCD10001**943
- **ABCD10002**981